# Should we [uninstall] this tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I've come across the [uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) tag. Is it a meta tag that should be burninated?

If it isn't burninated, should it be renamed [uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstallation) to make it a noun rather than a verb?

Comment: I find baffling that a site that focuses on programming (and the tools used for programming) needs to ask other programmers how to run basic installation/uninstalltion routines.

Answer (score 3):

This is a meta-tag. It only has meaning in the context of other tags.

- If a question is about uninstalling product X, it should be tagged with X.
- If a question is about tools to generate installers and uninstallers, it should be tagged with the tags for these tools.
- If a question is about problems encountered while manually writing an uninstaller, it should be tagged with tags appropriate to that problem. For example, if the targeted platform is Windows and the problem is with registry entries, it should in all likeliness be tagged with [registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registry). The fact that the purpose of the registry modification is uninstalling, is almost never essential to the problem.

Answer (score -3):

I believe both the tag and the distinction between [uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) and [uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstallation) is still useful for the very reason that one is a noun and one a verb.

**Uninstallation** would seem to refer to a specific process that is known followed, like the exe to uninstall an application (Likely the official one). However a quick search tells us the tag [uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstallation) is not currently being used. I propose that this tag be synonymous with the [uninstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstaller) which has 144 questions tagged at the time of writing.

While **Uninstall** the verb, refers to uninstalling via the official uninstalling method, cleanup of leftover files and for software where an official uninstallation process is not properly given or not obvious. There are 1,219 questions tagged "Uninstall" at the time of writing.